# Why does Flowplayer starts muted?

Tags: php, jquery, flowplayer

I'm using the 3.2.7 version of Flowplayer but a few days ago it started behaving strange. Whenever the website loads, the player shows up muted.

What might be wrong don't understand.

Comment: Maybe you should add a link to your website ? Or show us some code ?

Comment: I cant share the url right now, sorry.
can't u tell from the behavior?

Comment: You said "but a few days ago it started behaving strange", that means it was working in the beginning, maybe you have changed some soft config ? So did you try to open the website with another browser/OS/PC ?

Comment: yea quite possibel.
today I switched to 3.2.11 but player loads muted.
And yea, check this page http://code.google.com/p/flowplayer-core/issues/detail?id=486

Comment: i viewed that link wich is "automuted" for some persons, and i tried it with Firefox(12.0) on mac it works fine (without automute)

Comment: automute? its not documented. is it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12100/discussion-between-jey-keu-and-hamza-dzcyberdev)

Answer (score 0):

Flowplayer saves user settings to cookies. If You open video within flowplayer and change the volume level, close the video/page/browser and open another video within flowplayer - the volume level should be the same as previously set.

If You open the video that starts muted that should be because of last setting the volume level to zero. Try next:

Open the video, press pause, set the volume level to maximum, press play, close video/page/browser and try to open another (or the same) video. The volume level should be set to max.