# flowplayer starts muted - why?

Tags: javascript, flowplayer, mute

I have found this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877979/why-does-flowplayer-starts-muted) but with no apparent solution. flowplayer starts muted on my Mac in firefox, safari or chrome. This is the code I'm using, can someone point me in the right direction ? It is flowplayer 3.2.16 if this is of interest.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    player = flowplayer("player", "/libs/flowplayer/flowplayer.swf", {
        plugins: {audio: {url: '/libs/flowplayer/flowplayer.audio.swf'},controls: {url: '/libs/flowplayer/flowplayer.controls.swf'}}, 
        clip: {autoPlay: false, autoBuffering: true}
    }).ipad();
    $(".rmRating").jRating({type:'big',length:5,showRateInfo:false,decimalLength:0,rateMax:5,step: true});
    $('i.rex-player').on('click', function() {
        var c = {url: $(this).data('url'), coverImage: {url: "<?=$item->thumb;?>",scaling: 'orig'}};
        player.play(c);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the combination of autoBuffering and not having loaded a clip at all. For further details see the [flowplayer forum.](http://flowplayer.org/forum/#!/moot/15938)